# How do I fix a popped-out left joystick on my Xbox Series S/X controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-series-x-series-s

[image: picture of controller]

Was playing GTA and threw it at the ground from about 1 foot off the ground, and somehow it came out, though it doesn’t go back in. I don’t have the tools to fix this as I have seen tutorials and need to do quite a bit, so I’ll ask: should I take it to a repair place and have them do it quickly or order tools to fix it on my own?

Comment: This isn't really on topic for our site. Seeking guidance on whether you take it somewhere for repair or buy tools to do it yourself will only lead to subjective answers.

Comment: Why do people maltreat pads while playing still puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer you'll get is "It depends if it's under warranty".

Take it to GameStop (or similar), and ask them. They'll know how best to deal with it.